# What are these design elements often found in vintage newspapers and texts called?

Tags: terminology, style-identification, vintage

I've been on a search for a while now but I can't figure out the term for this design element. I'm not even really sure what to look up. I tried going through terms associated with typography but no dice. You find it used a lot in vintage texts like newspaper ads and wanted posters where identical symbols would be used on either side of a large bold text to create emphasis. Sometimes the symbols would be stars, sometimes dots, and sometimes these sharp darts.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Flourishes, ornaments, fleurons, dingbats, embellishments.

Basically any term which describes additional, possibly unnecessary, ornamental, items. There's no real *specific* typography term. 
<sub>(Except perhaps dingbat which designates a font file containing non-alphanumeric glyhs. 
And fleuron generally refers to more "flowery" ornamental glyphs.)</sub>

In the sample image, the rules above and below are as much flourishes, ornaments, embellishments, as the diamonds.

Comment: My brain has been expanded with wonderful new terms today like "fleuron" and "line-shaped dinkus" due to this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Never heard "dinkus".. that seems like a jovial term.  Looking it up, dinkus seems to *specifically* refer to three asterisks in a row. So now, you've also expanded my terminology.  I forgot fleuron.. added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rules above and below (of which there are fancier versions) are also sometimes referred to as **dividers**.

Comment: Yes, but it appears the question is not about those.